# Не работает Get-запрос в bat-файле

Tags: get, bat, wget

Для отправки Get-запроса использую утилиту WGET. Через командную строку команда выполняется и запрос уходит. Когда тоже самое пытаюсь выполнить через bat-файл, то ничего не происходит.

```
@echo off
c:
cd C:\test\web\result_send\
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe"   --no-check-certificate 
"http://192.168.1.5:8080/test_send/send_request.php?
send=true"  -O.check.html
```

**192.168.1.5** - другой компьютер в локальной сети и через браузер я его вижу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает передача через bat-файл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю что это было и как это объяснить, но я создала рядом со старым батником новый, копировала в него тот же код, но назвала по-другому (в моем случае, старый bat-файл имел название **integration_test.bat**, а новый называется просто  **test.bat**) и это сработало. Теперь данные отправляются!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать все в одну строку, в команде не должно быть перевода строки.

```
"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate "http://192.168.1.5:8080/test_send/send_request.php?send=true"  -O.check.html
```

Comment: "C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe" --no-check-certificate "http://192.168.1.5:8080/test_send/send_request.php?send=true"  -O.check.html в командной строке работает, а в bat-файле нет(

Comment: Тогда добавьте в конце вашего кода timeout 60, чтобы посмотреть сообщение об ошибке

Comment: он не ждет  это время, сразу же завершается

Comment: timeout /t 60 /nobreak

Comment: не ждет(( в какое бы место в скрипте не засунула((